# Error initiliazing container job in a Hosted Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I want to run a skopeo container as a container job.

I keep getting this error message during the **Initialize containers** step

`Error response from daemon: Container 7e741e4aafb30bb89e1dfb830c1cb69fa8d47d219f28cc7b8e57727253632256 is not running`

my pipeline looks like this:

```
  - job: publish_branch_image
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    container: docker.io/ananace/skopeo:latest
    steps:
    - script: |
        # clean branchname for imagename
        export COMMIT_IMAGE="$(Image.TagName)"
        export TARGET_IMAGE="$(Image.Name)":$(echo $(Build.SourceBranch) | sed 's./.-.g')
        echo "Pushing to ${TARGET_IMAGE}"
        skopeo copy docker://${COMMIT_IMAGE} docker://${TARGET_IMAGE} --src-creds="$(Registry.USER):$(Registry.PASSWORD)" --dest-creds="$(Registry.USER):$(Registry.PASSWORD)"
      displayName: publish-branch-release-image
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the detail logs here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems that the [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ananace/skopeo/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) is not running, we could run the cmd `docker pull docker.io/ananace/skopeo:latest` to pull the image and run it via `docker run docker.io/ananace/skopeo:latest`, then we could use it.

**Update1**

Thanks for michiel sharing, according to the doc [Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints) and [Linux-based containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#linux-based-containers):

Containers can be hosted on registries other than Docker Hub. To host an image on Azure Container Registry or another private container registry, add a service connection to the private registry. Then you can reference it in a container spec:

```
container:
  image: xxx/xxx:tag
  endpoint: xxx
```

Comment: I found the reason why it was not working, it is a known limitation of container jobs. It might not work when the image has an entrypoint
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#linux-based-containers

Comment: Hi @michielThai, Thanks for your sharing, I have update the answer, you could check it. In addition, do you mind converting the comment into an answer and accepting it as the answer? It could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)